# Permutation in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, permutation, masm

I am trying to make a program that finds the permutation after taking 2 numbers as a user input. I understand how permutations work, but I am new to Assembly and can not figure out how to set up a loop that would allow me to calculate the permutation. This is what I have so far

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
EXTRN _printf:PROC
EXTRN _scanf:PROC
.STACK  4096            ; reserve 4096-byte stack

.DATA                   ; reserve storage for data
x       DWORD   5 DUP (?)
perm     DWORD   ?
msg db      "Enter a number:", 10, 0
format1 db  "%d", 0     
format2 db  "Permutation = %d", 10, 0

.CODE                           ; start of main program code
main    PROC        

    ;initialization
    mov esi, offset x
    mov ecx, 2
    mov eax, 0
next:
    ;prompt for input: use printf(msg)
    pusha                   ; restore all registers
    push offset msg         ;single parameter
    call _printf
    add esp, 4              ; restore top of the stack
    popa                    ;restore all registers

    ;input: use scanf("%d, &x)
    pusha               ;push all registers
    push esi            ;first parameter: address x
    push offset format1 ;second parameter: format string
    call _scanf
    add esp, 8
    popa                ;restore all registers

    ;computation

    add eax, dword ptr [esi]       
    add esi, 4
    loop next

    mov perm, eax         ; perm to memory

    ;output: use printf("Permutation = %d", perm)
    push perm               ; first paramenter address perm
    push offset format2     ; second parameter: format string
    call _printf
    add esp, 8              ; restore top of the stack
    ret 0   
main    ENDP

END                              ; end of source code
```

I know the computation part isn't set up for permutations yet, but how would I make the program loop the correct number of times? I'm using `ECX` as the loop counter, but how can I manipulate it with the inputted values, so it would iterate the number of times needed?

I'm using the equation `P(n,k) = n(n-1)(n-2)…(n-(k-1))` to find the total number of permutations. An example would be input 5,2 and output 20

Comment: This will print number1+number2 (the sum is happening already during input)? You know how permutations work, but I'm not going to guess what you mean by that, so put some example input and expected output, and some algorithm description, how you want to achieve that. Actually after that you can fill up the algorithm with asm instructions and you are done... (I'm not sure what you want to permute from those two input values)

Comment: if you read the last part I already said that, the way I am trying to find permutations is  P(n,k) = n(n-1)(n-2)…(n-(k-1)), i'm not sure how to loop through it and do the multiplications necessary.

Comment: That's number of k-permutations of n, not permutations themselves? (as I said, some example would help a lot to make sure the readers of question follow you correctly ... at first read I though you want to permute digits of those numbers, like for input 1234, 1432 to print all 1234 1243 ... till 1432).

Comment: okay I have added the equation and a sample input and output to the question hopefully that makes my goal clear

Answer (score 1):

Main loop code:

```
    ; ebx = read "n"
    ; ecx = read "k"
    mov   eax,1   ; intermediate result
    jecxz P_n_k_finished ; for k = 0: P(n,k) = n! / n! = 1
P_n_k_loop:
    imul  eax,ebx ; calculate initial part of n!
    dec   ebx
    dec   ecx     ; using first k factors, then stop
    jnz   P_n_k_loop
P_n_k_finished:
    ; eax = P(n,k) (if not overflown)
```

For completeness, verify validity of `[n, k]: 0 <= k <= n <= 12` (to fit `n!` into 32b, for smaller "k" even "n" may be above 12 and still the result will fit, but 12 is last one to fit the result for k=n case).

I'm using `IMUL` (signed multiply) as it's a tiny fraction faster when used in r32,r32 form (discarding upper 32b of result, so edx is preserved too), but the algorithm is designed to work only with non-negative `[n,k]` (like `P(0, 0) = 1`).

I'm not sure what is problematic for you, for me this looks pretty straightforward and simple, so just ask under the answer if something is not clear.

Comment: 2-operand IMUL is only signed in its flag-setting.  The register output exactly matches the low-half result you'd get from MUL with the same inputs, because this is how 2's complement multiplies work.  This is why there isn't a 2-operand MUL.  The insn ref manual points this out, too.: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html